# Is there a way to re-set the "hosts" variable within a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am tasked with creating a playbook, where I perform the following operations:

- Fetch information from a YAML file (the file contains details on VLANs)
- Cycle through the YAML objects and verify which subnet contains the IP, then return the object
- The object contains also a definition of the `inventory_hostname` where to run the Ansible playbook

At the moment, I have the following (*snippet*):

**Playbook**:

```yaml
- name: "Playbook"
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: "localhost"
  tasks: 
    - name: "add host"
      add_host:
        name: "{{ vlan_target }}"
    - name: "debug"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

The defaults file defines the `target_host` as an empty string `""` and then it is evaluated within another role task, like so (*snippet*):

**Role**:

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    vlan_object: "vlan | trim | from_json | first"

- name: "set facts based on IP address"
  set_fact:
    vlan_name: "{{ vlan_object.name }}"
    vlan_target: "{{ vlan_object.target }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

What I am trying to achieve is to change the `hosts:` variable so that I can use the right target, since the IP/VLAN should reside on a specific device.

I have tried to put the aforementioned task above the `add_host`, or even putting in the same playbook, like so:

```yaml
- name: "Set_variables"
  hosts: "localhost"
  tasks:
    - name: "Set target host"
      import_role:
        name: test
        tasks_from: target_selector

- name: "Playbook"
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: "localhost"
```

Adding a `debug` clause to the above playbook sets the right target, but it is not re-used below, making me think that the variable is not set globally, but within that run.

I am looking for a way to set the target, based on a variable that I am passing to the playbook.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Facts are always related to hosts. You could do two things: set a fact for all hosts: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16049#issuecomment-474093497 or access it on the host where is was set: `hostvars.localhost.vlan_target`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've managed to do this by setting the variable through the localhost, and then calling it with `hostvars.localhost.vlan_target`. You may post your answer if you want, and I'll award you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global facts are not a thing, [at best you can assign a fact to all hosts in the play](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16049#issuecomment-474093497), but since you are looking to use the said fact to add an host, this won't be a solution for your use case.

You can access facts of another hosts via the [`hostvars` special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), though. It is a dictionary where the keys are the names of the hosts.

The usage of the role is not relevant to your issue at hand, so, in the demonstration below, let's put this aside.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks: 
    - set_fact:
        ## fake object, since we don't have the structure of your JSON 
        vlan_object:
          name: foo
          target: bar

    - set_fact:
        vlan_name: "{{ vlan_object.name }}"
        vlan_target: "{{ vlan_object.target }}"
      run_once: true

    - add_host:
        name: "{{ vlan_target }}"

- hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.vlan_target }}"
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts
```

This would yield

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [add_host] **************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [bar] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [bar] => 
  ansible_play_hosts:
  - bar
```

Comment: What is the use of "add_host" here, could you tell me? Thanks.